# password verify function error ora - 06503

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created a function that Password should be at least 8 characters long.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION password_function (
  username      VARCHAR2,
  password      VARCHAR2,
  old_password  VARCHAR2)
  RETURN BOOLEAN AS
BEGIN
  IF LENGTH(password) < 8 THEN
    RETURN FALSE;
  ELSE
    RETURN TRUE;
  END IF;
END password_function;
/
```

than I have alter user1 profile like

"alter profile user1 limit password_verify_function password_function"

then when I tried to create a user with user1 profile and 9 character password I am getting following error.

SQL> create user test identified by Passowrd1 profile user1;
create user test identified by Passowrd1
*
ERROR at line 1:

ORA-28003: password verification for the specified password failed

ORA-06503: PL/SQL: function returned without value

could you please tell me is there any problem in my function? and how to resolve it?

Comment: the `ORA-28003:` looks like it's ok, what happens if you enter a correct password?

Comment: "ORA-06503: PL/SQL: function returned without value" says that your function doesn't return any value (in some case maybe). Are you sure you listed exactly the same code which was used when you created the user?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you have problems with code you don't show to us.

Your function `password_function ()` has to be used somewhere (I guess in another function) and it seems, that a return is missing in that calling function.

Check if there is a return after your call of `alter profile ...`.

Another thing:

```
IF LENGTH(password) < 8 THEN
    RETURN FALSE;   
ELSE
    RETURN TRUE;   
END IF;
```

This code will return true if the new password is null!

> LENGTH(null) = null

Better would be:

> NVL(LENGTH(null), 0) < 8